# UIPageViewController reset states swift

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

i would like to ask if there is any ways we can reset our view in UIPageViewController implementation. For example I have two views,
in View A, there is a button which changed text upon clicking as well as a tableview. Once i have clicked the button or when i have scrolled to the middle in my tableview, when i have swiped to View B, my states in View A will not be reset when I go back to View A where the button's text are not reset and my tableview is in the middle where from where I scrolled earlier.
Is there any ways once we move pages between UIPageViewController, the pages reset their states?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "It's kind of complicated."

The background:

If you only have 2 pages in your page view controller the page view controller will probably keep strong references to both, and so they will retain their state as you page back and forth between them.

If you have more than 2 pages, and are not showing 2 pages at the same time and using a center spine, the pages that are not either currently visible or next to be displayed will likely get released and you will then recreate them when the user displays them. In that case the pages won't remember their state unless you do extra work so that they save their state when they are moved off-screen.

### Your case:

You always want your pages to reset when the user swipes to a different page and then back again.

I'd suggest you write your pages' view controllers logic so they respond to `viewWillAppear(animated:)` by resetting themselves to their starting state. (scrolling table views to the top, resetting button states, or whatever.)

Ideally, you might want to make that an option that is controlled by a flag (`resetsOnAppear: Bool`). That way if you later decide you don't want that to happen, you can just set the flag to false and don't have to refactor your code.